# Since $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{dy}{dx}^{-1}$, why doesn't $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x} = [\frac{d}{dx}x^2]^{-1}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is also true that $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1}(x) = [\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x)]^{-1}$,
 so since the positive square root is the inverse function of $x^2$ from $0 \to \infty$, why doesn't the principle of $\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{dy}{dx}^{-1}$ hold, and why is $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x} \neq \frac{1}{2x}$ ?

**EDIT**: Let me clarify the notation. What I'm asking is, since the derivative of arcsin is 1 over the derivative of sin, why isn't the derivative of the inverse of x^2 1 over the derivative of x^2

Comment: Check your first line....

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, could you be more precise?, I've thought about this for a while, I wouldn't ask if it was obvious to me.

Comment: $-1$ is doing two different jobs - indicating a power ($x^{-1}=\frac 1x$), and indicating an inverse function. Since you are mixing up notation it is unclear what you are trying to say. If you clarify your notation, you will most likely clarify the problem.

Comment: @MarkBennet, I don't see what's wrong with the notation, I thought it was standard that $\sin^{-1}(x)$ stood for $\arcsin$? I'm asking, since the derivative of arcsin is 1 over the derivative of sin, why isn't the derivative of the inverse of x^2 1 over the derivative of x^2.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff You can be interested by [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer, Thanks for the link, it helped clarify things for me.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I'm glad if my comments helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y=x^2$ so that $x=\sqrt y$

We have $\cfrac {dy}{dx}=2x$ and $\cfrac {dx}{dy}=\dfrac 1{2\sqrt y}=\cfrac 1{2x}$

Comment: But so why is the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$, $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$? Wait, nevermind I got it. Wow...thank you.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff Because the derivative of $y(x)=\sqrt{x}$ with respect to $x$ is different from the derivative of $x(y)=\sqrt{y}$ with respect to $y$ in general. If you denote by $f$ the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$, you have $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{2f(x)}$. You mix up $x$ as a dummy variable and $x(y)$ as a function of the dummy variable $y$.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer, Thank you, this is very helpful. You're right, I was confusing those two things.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if $y = \sqrt{x}$ that $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \left(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\right)^{-1}$. I don't believe your second expression is saying that.